# Looking for Excel VBA to generate rows based on IF queries

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large list of AD users with either Read only or RW permissions in one of our apps. We need to create a host of new AD groups to populate with these users depending on their current direct permissions but I can't see how I can automate the data to easily do this. TIA advance for any help or guidance.

Current data set (Around 2000 lines)

```
    Safe     UserName     Read permissions     RW permissions
    Safe1    User1        Yes                  Yes
    Safe1    User2        Yes                  No      
    Safe1    User3        Yes                  Yes
    Safe1    User4        Yes                  No  
    Safe2    User1        Yes                  Yes
    Safe2    User2        Yes                  No      
    Safe2    User3        Yes                  Yes
    Safe2    User4        Yes                  No
```

Ideal data set (In rows on a new sheet preferably)

```
    Safe     AD Group         Userlist
    Safe1    Safe1-ReadGroup  User1,User2,User3,User4
    Safe1    Safe1-RWGroup    User1,User3
    Safe2    Safe2-ReadGroup  User1,User2,User3,User4
    Safe2    Safe2-RWGroup    User1,User3
```

I have all the master data in one sheet and hopefully I can take the expected data outcome and push it all into AD in one go.

Comment: Are you using Excel 365? That would give you more options, using TEXTJOIN and dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 1):

### Regroup (Transform) Data Using VBA

[image]

```vb
Sub RegroupData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_TABLE_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const SRC_FLAG As String = "Yes"
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_TABLE_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_DELIMITER As String = ", "
    
    ' 0 - Safe - the unique column
    ' 1 - UserName - the return column
    ' 2 - Read Permissions - 1st flag column
    ' 3 - RW Permissions - 2nd flag column
    Dim sColumns(): sColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    ' If you add another 'flag' column, you'll have to add another suffix!
    
    ' These two are related to the flag (Permission) columns
    ' (indexes 2 and 3 i.e. columns 3 and 4 in this particular case).
    Dim dSuffixes(): dSuffixes = VBA.Array("-ReadGroup", "-RWGroup")
    ' There will always be 3 resulting (destination) columns.
    Dim dHeaders(): dHeaders = VBA.Array("Safe", "AD Group", "Userlist")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Reference the source range.

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_TABLE_CELL)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    With sfCell.CurrentRegion
        Set srg = sfCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - sfCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - sfCell.Column)
        srCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1
        scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    End With
    
    If scCount < Application.Max(sColumns) Then
        MsgBox "Not enough columns.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If srCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough rows.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set srg = srg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
            
    ' Return the columns' values in 2D one-based single-column arrays
    ' held in a jagged array.
    
    Dim scUpper As Long: scUpper = UBound(sColumns)
    Dim sJag(): ReDim sJag(0 To scUpper)
    
    Dim sData(), sc As Long
    
    For sc = 0 To scUpper
        If srCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            sData(1, 1) = srg.Columns(sColumns(sc)).Value
        Else
            sData = srg.Columns(sColumns(sc)).Value
        End If
        sJag(sc) = sData
    Next sc

    ' Return the unique values and their rows in a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sStr = CStr(sJag(0)(sr, 1))
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
            If Not dict.Exists(sStr) Then ' 'sStr' isn't in the keys of 'dict'
                ' Add the string to a new key of 'dict'
                ' and add a new collection to its corresponding item.
                Set dict(sStr) = New Collection '
            'Else ' 'sStr' is already in the keys of 'dict'; do nothing
            End If
            dict(sStr).Add sr ' add the row to the collection
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim dsUpper As Long: dsUpper = UBound(dSuffixes)
    Dim dsCount As Long: dsCount = dsUpper + 1 ' zero-based!
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count * dsCount + 1 ' headers!

    If drCount = 1 Then ' headers!
        MsgBox "No valid data found (dictionary).", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(dHeaders) + 1 ' zero-based!
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    ' Write the matching data to the destination array.
    
    ' Write headers.
    For sc = 1 To dcCount
        dData(1, sc) = dHeaders(sc - 1) ' one-based vs zero-based!
    Next sc
    
    Dim dLen As Long: dLen = Len(DST_DELIMITER)
    Dim drStrings() As String: ReDim drStrings(0 To dsUpper)
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 2 - dsCount ' headers!
    
    Dim Key, srItem, ds As Long, cdr As Long, dStr As String
    
    ' Write data.
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        dr = dr + dsCount
        For Each srItem In dict(Key)
            For ds = 0 To dsUpper
                sStr = CStr(sJag(ds + 2)(srItem, 1))
                If StrComp(sStr, SRC_FLAG, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    dStr = CStr(sJag(1)(srItem, 1))
                    If Len(dStr) > 0 Then
                        drStrings(ds) = drStrings(ds) & dStr & DST_DELIMITER
                    End If
                End If
            Next ds
        Next srItem
        For ds = 0 To dsUpper
            cdr = dr + ds
            dData(cdr, 1) = Key
            dData(cdr, 2) = Key & dSuffixes(ds)
            sStr = drStrings(ds)
            If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
                dData(cdr, 3) = Left(sStr, Len(sStr) - dLen)
                drStrings(ds) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next ds
    Next Key
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_TABLE_CELL)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    ' Clear.
    With dfCell.CurrentRegion
        Set drg = dfCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - dfCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - dfCell.Column)
    End With
    drg.Clear
    
    ' Write
    Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Apply formatting.
    With drg
        ' Headers.
        With .Rows(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .BorderAround xlContinuous
        End With
        ' Data.
        With .Resize(drCount - 1).Offset(1)
        
        End With
        ' Table (range).
        .BorderAround xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ' Table (range) entire columns.
        With .EntireColumn
            .AutoFit
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data regrouped.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

- To illustrate one aspect of the code's flexibility, you could add another *Permissions* column using e.g. the following two lines instead, where the last *Permissions* column is returned first.

  ```
  Dim sColumns(): sColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 5, 3, 4)
  Dim dSuffixes(): dSuffixes = VBA.Array("-Other", "-ReadGroup", "-RWGroup")
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: VBA code

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim aData, Dic, sPerm, sKey, i
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, sShtName As String
    aData = Sheets("Sheet1").[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
        ' ReadGroup users list
        If aData(i, 3) = "Yes" Then
            sKey = aData(i, 1) & "-ReadGroup"
            If Dic.Exists(sKey) Then
                Dic(sKey) = Dic(sKey) & "," & aData(i, 2)
            Else
                Dic(sKey) = aData(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
        ' RWGroup use list
        If aData(i, 4) = "Yes" Then
            sKey = aData(i, 1) & "-RWGroup"
            If Dic.Exists(sKey) Then
                Dic(sKey) = Dic(sKey) & "," & aData(i, 2)
            Else
                Dic(sKey) = aData(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    sShtName = "Output" 'update name as needed
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSht = Sheets(sShtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oSht Is Nothing Then
    ' Create new sheet
        Set oSht = Sheets.Add
        oSht.Name = "Output"
    Else
        oSht.Cells.Clear
        oSht.Select
    End If
    ' output table header
    [a1:c1] = Array("Safe", "AD Group", "UserList")
    ' column AD Group
    aData = Dic.keys
    Range("B2").Resize(Dic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(aData)
    ' column UserList
    Range("C2").Resize(Dic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Dic.items)
    For i = 0 To UBound(aData)
        aData(i) = Split(aData(i), "-")(0)
    Next
    ' column Safe
    Range("A2").Resize(Dic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(aData)
    Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

---

Option 2: Power Query

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    AddedRG = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ReadGroup", each if [Read permissions] = "Yes" then [UserName] else null),
    AddedRWG = Table.AddColumn(AddedRG, "RWGroup", each if [RW permissions] = "Yes" then [UserName] else null),
    RemovedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddedRWG,{"UserName", "Read permissions", "RW permissions"}),
    GroupedRG = Table.Group(RemovedColumns, {"Safe"}, {{"UserList", each Text.Combine([ReadGroup], ","), type text}}),
    GroupedRGCol =  Table.AddColumn(GroupedRG, "AD Group", each [Safe] & "-ReadGroup"),
    GroupedRWG = Table.Group(RemovedColumns, {"Safe"}, {{"UserList", each Text.Combine([RWGroup], ","), type text}}),
    GroupedRWGCol =  Table.AddColumn(GroupedRWG, "AD Group", each [Safe] & "-RWGroup"),
    AppendedTable = Table.Combine({GroupedRGCol, GroupedRWGCol}),
    Output = Table.ReorderColumns(AppendedTable,{"Safe", "AD Group", "UserList"})
in
    Output
```

---

Option 3: PY formula in Excel (just for fun)

```py
df=xl("Table1[#All]", headers=True)
rw_df = df[df['RW permissions'] == 'Yes'].drop(columns=['RW permissions'])
grp_rw = rw_df.groupby(['Safe'])['UserName'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
grp_rw['AD Group'] = grp_rw['Safe'] + '-RWGroup'
r_df = df[df['Read permissions'] == 'Yes'].drop(columns=['Read permissions'])
grp_r = r_df.groupby(['Safe'])['UserName'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
grp_r['AD Group'] = grp_r['Safe'] + '-ReadGroup'
df_output = pd.concat([grp_r, grp_rw], axis=0).rename(columns={'UserName': 'UserList'}).reset_index()[['Safe', 'AD Group', 'UserList']]
```

[image]